# Navigation bar back button invisible

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

There seems to be multiple questions relating to this problem, yet none of them can provide a proper working answer.

[image: Navigation Controller]
I'm using a Navigation Controller in my storyboard to provide navigation to a settings view with a couple of subviews. `Table View` contains a table with multiple entries, one for each subview. They all have a segue attached to them with identifiers such as `SettingsViewToNotificationsSettingsView`.

```
Navigation Controller
  -- Relationship to -- >
  Table View
    -- Perform manual segue -->
    Settings subview 1
    Settings subview 2
    Settings subview 3
    Settings subview 4
```

When selecting an element in the list, the following line of code would be called:

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("SettingsViewToNotificationsSettingsView", sender: self)
```

The transition works fine, and the back button does actually transition back to the overview, but it's **not visible**. I am quite sure, it's not because of the title of the parent view, as it has a title set.

It's even long enough to move the label of each subview off the center to the right, to fit in there. If I programmatically change the title to something shorter (such as `ABC`), the subview's title is centered again.

Please tell me if any other information is required. Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you add a screenshot of that view?

Comment: Try to set another color(such as black, red) to see if the back button will appear? You may set the tint color as the same as the bar tint color.

Comment: I kinda thought this happened, but I couldn't find where I've set tintColor and barTintColor to the same value. Now I've found it, and I have indeed set them to the same value... Silly me, but thank you! :)